# Traffic flow between network-interface due to VPC peering

Tags: amazon-web-services, voip, vpc-peering, freeswitch

We have a scenario, where we have SBC instance which has three network interface attached to it(1,2,3). SBC instance along with network interface 1(management),2 are deployed in VPC A, where as interface 3, which is network interface from VPC B (Different subnet no IP overlap) attached to the instance via cross connect. VPC A and VPC B have a VPC peering connection. SBC instance is running an application that handles(Audio and Video) Media, we are seeing some  (hirpining) behavior on the SBC due to a media latching feature.

1. Can this be due to VPC peering?
2. As VPC peering is happening before packets arrive at the Network-interface interface, SBC doesn't have much insight? Is there a way to identify root cause the problem using packets analysis?

Any insight is much appreciated.